# Formatting yaml to include a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, configuration, yaml

Sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm very new to yaml configurations (+ configurations in general) and everything is a bit confusing. I have a file that goes as such:

```
hosts:
  - hostid: 43842
    tag: "name"
    items:
      port: "some port"
      in: 2342124
      out: 2349334
  - hostid: 24586
    tag: "..."
```

And so on. This configuration works with my project (made in python), but I would like to add a few more port values under 'items' and have them have their own in/out coordinates. I can't seem to find the right format for it. What are some ways to approach this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have list of objects inside items. Multiple ports.

```
hosts:
  - hostid: 43842
    tag: "name"
    items:
      - port: "some port"
        in: 2342124
        out: 2349334
      - port: "some other port"
        in: 2342124
        out: 2349334
```

Or if you want multiple in/out values under same port you can add a list under some attribute, for example data

```
hosts:
  - hostid: 43842
    tag: "name"
    items:
      port: "some port"
      data:
        - in: 2342124
          out: 2349334
        - in: 2342124
          out: 2349334
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `items` is a type `dict` meaning you can't have keys that are the same or you overwrite the values over and over.  What you need is a `list` of `dict`s.

We could use `pyyaml` (`pip install pyyaml`) to accomplish this.  Here is an example

```
import yaml

contents = """
hosts:
  - hostid: 43842
    tag: "name"
    items:
      port: "some port"
      in: 2342124
      out: 2349334"""

# cook the data a little to make items a list instead of a dict
data = yaml.full_load(contents)
for d in data.get('hosts'):
    d['items'] = [d.get('items')]

# modify whatever we are interested in
for host in data.get('hosts'):
    if host.get('hostid') == 43842:
        host['items'].append({
            'port': 'another port',
            'in': 12345,
            'out': 12345
        })

# show our modifications
print(yaml.dump(data))
```

This prints:

```
hosts:
- hostid: 43842
  items:
  - in: 2342124
    out: 2349334
    port: some port
  - in: 12345
    out: 12345
    port: another port
  tag: name
```